# Install dig on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dig

How can I install "dig" on Ubuntu 14.04 minimal ?

I tried:

```
apt-get install dig
```

It didn't work. Seems its in some different package included but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dig` is contained in `dnsutils` package. Try this way:

```
apt-get install dnsutils
```